# How to create a library in Kotlin and use it from projects that target javascript or java?

Tags: javascript, java, kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

I am looking at how I can create a common library that is used by both front-end and back-end codebases.  I'd like to be able to create a library that is written purely in Kotlin, compile it, and register said artifact(s) to be imported as dependencies from both js (using npm) and kotlin-java (using maven).  Is this a workflow that is supported or possible?  If so, what are the approaches to doing so?

Comment: Multiplatform library compilation is neither oficially supported nor documented. In http://slack.kotlinlang.org/, there's a #multiplatform channel, you can try asking there.

Answer (score 0):

When using Gradle instead of using `compile ...kotlin-stdlib-jre8` (or any other `jre`) use `compile ...kotlin-stdlib`. This should be enough though remember not to use Java-only features (such as most of the reflection features) as they [won't work](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-reflection.html) when using JavaScript